# How to combine two sets of data

Tags: scala

I have a list of User objects, and each of those User objects looks like this:

```
case class User(username: String, firstName: String, lastName: String, batchId: Int, imageUrl: String)
```

I want to go through that List, pull out all the usernames, and send those usernames off to an API which will return a JSON list containing Twitter specific information (e.g. profile info and twitter profile image). I then want to take that list of returned objects and add the information in each of those to my original list of objects, matching by the username.

How can I do this in a functional way?

Answer (score 1):

You do it pretty much as you said.  I'll assume that you can figure out how to get in touch with the API and get JSON back, and the "how do I make it functional" part is the core of the question.

If you'll be querying in a batch, and you might not get back a username you requested, you can do something like the following.

```
val usernames = allUsers.map(_.username)
val json = myGetJSONRoutine(usernames)
val parsed = makeMapFromJSON(json)   // Returns Map[String, TwitterInfo]
val newUsers = allUsers.map{ x =>
  parsed.get(x.username).map{ t => 
     // Generate the updated user object here
     x.copy(imageUrl = t.imageUrl)
  }.getOrElse(x)  // Fall back to pre-existing object
}
```

Anyway, the basic steps are: map out the usernames, get the JSON, parse it into a map from username to whatever new info you need, and then map through the user records updating them with new information.  Then you stop using `allUsers` and start using `newUsers`.

That's really the whole trick: instead of updating existing records, you regenerate the list with new records based on the old ones (`copy` is built for this kind of updating).

If your user record needs to be different after you get twitter info (that is, the original objects do not just contain stubs for the data), then you also need to write a default mapper from the un-twitterified `User` to the `UserWithTwitter` class.  Or your `User` could have a `twittery` field that is an `Option[TwitterInfo]`, which you start off setting to `None` and then `copy(twittery = Some(t))` if you actually found that info.

A full tutorial on using a web API to get JSON, and then to parse JSON, is outside the scope of one question.  (But e.g. Play can do it.)